# HowTo get work Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and Qt Visual Studio Add-in?

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2010, qt4, add-in

Greetings everyone!

**Question**: does any one have a success with combining [Microsoft Visual Studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us) with [Qt Visual Studio Add-in](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/visual-studio-add-in)?

I have tried to use `MSVS2010` with `Qt VS Add-in 1.1.5`, but no luck.

---

PS: no never mind what exactly arch or OS, I used Win7 x32...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to wait till `Qt 4.7`...

Because [this](http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-5374) one says so..

Comment: Yep, we have to wait till 1.1.6 and 4.7.0: `VS 2010 support will be in 1.1.6, which will be released together with Qt 4.7.0`, - Jörg Bornemann