# Configuration of Qt in Visual C++ 2010

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2010

I am using the Visual C++ 2010 compiler. How can Qt be compiled in Visual C++?

Comment: What actions did you try and what problems happened? Start with instructions included with Qt, you need to pick (or search on the web) right config for VS2010.

Comment: @c-programmer Have a look this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475011/howto-get-work-microsoft-visual-studio-2010-and-qt-visual-studio-add-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of Qt (4.6) doesn't support Visual Studio 2010:
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/supported-platforms.html
However as you can see on that link, Qt 4.7 does plan to support it.

Can you use Visual Studio 2008 instead?  I have been using it with the Qt plugin.  You might need the full version of VS 2008 though - I don't think you can install the Qt plugin in the Express version.

If the full version of Visual Studio 2008 isn't an option, you might be better off using [Eclipse with Qt integration](http://qt.nokia.com/developer/eclipse-integration/), or [QtCreator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools) (available from the Qt website.)  If you are planning on compiling your Qt project on other platforms, one of these would probably be a better choice in any case, since the Visual Studio project format doesn't translate to other platforms (to my knowledge.)

Answer (score -2):

if you want, I can send you a detailed description of the installation and compile procedure with Visual Studio 2008